# How do I calculate days since a record entry? Android, SQLite, Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database with a field for a stored date. I would like to be able calculate the days between the recorded date and today.

I ended up using:

```
mDb.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_PLANTS_TABLE+" SET "+ KEY_PLANT_DAYS+ 
            " = (SELECT julianday('now') - julianday("+KEY_DATE+") FROM"+ DATABASE_PLANTS_TABLE+")");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select (strftime('%s','now')-strftime('%s', data1))/86400.0 as days from table
```

Comment: i ended up using something very similar to this. Much easier than bothering with jodatime since all i needed was this date calculation.
What i actually used is posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/) [Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Days.html) class for this:

```
Date dateInDb = getStoredDate();
Date today = new Date();
Days days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(dateInDb), new DateTime(today));
int numberOfDays = days.getDays();
```

Comment: I've downloaded Joda Time, not sure how to use it though. I've attempted to add the class directly to my project but get a source not found error when attempting to open it.

Comment: Been working on this currently the 'p' in p.getDays(); is unresolved

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Now i'm getting a force close which seems to be an android issue. No errors in debug and it happens when calling DateTime. a simple:   DateTime start = new DateTime(dateInDb); causes a force close